# Map a date to a integer 15 minutes intervals in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

I am dividing a 24 per day to 15 minutes intervals and and creating a list of 15 min integers intervals where 0 indicates 00:00 AM:, 1 is 00:15 AM, 95 is 11:45 PM and vice versa.

```
>>> time_len = int(24 * 60/15)
>>> time_range = list(range(0, time_len, 1))
>>> time_range
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]
```

Now lets say I have the following datetime object:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime_object1 = datetime.strptime('Jan 1 2020  9:15PM', '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
>>> datetime_object1
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 21, 15)
```

My question is if there is any way to map this time to a 15 min range I create above? For instance in the example above, datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 21, 15) would be equal 85 in that range.

Answer (score 2):

If my understanding of the question is correct, all you need to do is multiply the hours by 4 and add the result to the minutes divided by 15.

Something like:

```py
datetime_object1.hour * 4 + datetime_object1.minute // 15
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an alternate way that may accomplish all you need while being simpler.

Take the hours portion of the `datetime` object and multiply by 4. Now take the minutes portion of the `datetime` and divide by 60 then multiply by 4. Add those 2 results and you should have what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(datetime_object1.hour * 60/15) + (datetime_object1.minute/15)`
This takes the hour and minutes of the datetime_object1 and converts them to your interval.

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

Create on datetime object containing the midnight of your date:

```py
midnight = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

now we can simply:

```py
some_datetime = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 21, 15)

# get time difference
difference = some_datetime - midnight

# change unit to minutes
minutes = difference.total_seconds() / 60

# voila
print(minutes // 15)
```